# PSAD Status Firewall Setup Warning

Tags: 16.04, server, iptables, firewall

Every time I restart my Ubuntu 16.04 Server I receive the following in an email.

[-] You may just need to add a default logging rule to the
    'filter' 'INPUT' chain on HomeOne.  For more information,
    see the file "FW_HELP" in the psad sources directory or visit:

http://www.cipherdyne.org/psad/docs/fwconfig.html

The link states that I should add the following at the end of Input and Forward Chains.

```
iptables -A INPUT -j LOG
iptables -A FORWARD -j LOG
```

I already have the following at the end of my file but I can't find the Input or Forward chains.

```
iptables -A INPUT -j LOG
iptables -A FORWARD -j LOG
ip6tables -A INPUT -j LOG
ip6tables -A FORWARD -j LOG
```

While the email is nice to know when my server reboots (added to list of things to cron) I'm concerned that something isn't secured and or not set up correctly.

Am I missing something obvious or am I just not finding the Input and Forward chains? I swear I've looked for them though.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
Do the roles go in the following?

```
### The following defaults make sense for most installations, but note
### it is possible to include blocking rules in, say, the "nat" table
### using this functionality as well.  The following three lines provide
### usage examples:
#IPT_AUTO_CHAIN1              DROP, src, filter, INPUT, 1, PSAD_BLOCK_INPUT, 1;
#IPT_AUTO_CHAIN2              DROP, dst, filter, OUTPUT, 1, PSAD_BLOCK_OUTPUT, 1;
#IPT_AUTO_CHAIN3              DROP, both, filter, FORWARD, 1, PSAD_BLOCK_FORWARD, 1;
IPT_AUTO_CHAIN1             DROP, src, filter, INPUT, 1, PSAD_BLOCK_INPUT, 1;
IPT_AUTO_CHAIN2             DROP, dst, filter, OUTPUT, 1, PSAD_BLOCK_OUTPUT, 1;
IPT_AUTO_CHAIN3             DROP, both, filter, FORWARD, 1, PSAD_BLOCK_FORWARD, 1;
```

Would this question be better served on a different SE site?

**Edit** Output from `sudo iptables -L -n -v`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:67
1255  114K ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
1255  114K ufw-before-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
0     0 ufw-after-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
0     0 ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
0     0 ufw-reject-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
0     0 ufw-track-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 *       192.168.122.0/24     0.0.0.0/0           
0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
0     0 REJECT     all  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
0     0 ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
0     0 ufw-before-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
0     0 ufw-after-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
0     0 ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
0     0 ufw-reject-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
0     0 ufw-track-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
944  140K ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
944  140K ufw-before-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
103 13346 ufw-after-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
103 13346 ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
103 13346 ufw-reject-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
103 13346 ufw-track-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:137
0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:138
0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:139
0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:445
0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 4
0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
0     0 ufw-user-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
210 15780 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
938 84010 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
0     0 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 4
0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:67 dpt:68
107 14048 ufw-not-local  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251          udp dpt:5353
0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
107 14048 ufw-user-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
210 15780 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
631  111K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
103 13346 ufw-user-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
12   720 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST
95 13328 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
0     0 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10
0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1    60 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW
102 13286 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
12   720 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:22
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:80
95 13328 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 137,138 /* 'dapp_Samba' */
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 139,445 /* 'dapp_Samba' */

Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

**Edit**

Output of `sudo ufw status verbose`:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80                         DENY IN     Anywhere                  
137,138/udp (Samba)        ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
139,445/tcp (Samba)        ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    DENY IN     Anywhere (v6)             
137,138/udp (Samba (v6))   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
139,445/tcp (Samba (v6))   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: In an edit, add the output of `sudo iptables -L -n -v` to the question.  Obfuscate any IP addresses you want to hide, but keep the rest in place.

Comment: @ThomasWard Alright it's been added, thanks for you help!

Comment: So, it looks like you're permitting SSH and port 80 (HTTP) inbound in your `ufw` rules, is that accurate?

Comment: SSH should be setup, I don't recall ever setting up Port 80.

Comment: What do you mean you added those to the 'end of the file', which file? Generally you need to add it to before.rules and before6.rules (as you are using ufw),   Also the syntax of this file is that of single rules, rather than whole commands. So use:

 -A INPUT -j LOG
 -A FORWARD -j LOG

Or even better: 

-A INPUT -j LOG --log-tcp-options 
-A FORWARD -j LOG --log-tcp-options